# How to moves files two directories up using ssh?

Tags: shell

I am able to move files one directory up by using the following command:

```
mv * ..
```

but is there a way to move files two directories up?

Comment: I presume you mean while logged in to server via ssh?

Answer (score 8):

Is this a trick question?

```
mv * ../../
```

Answer (score 5):

I may be missing something obvious here, but I'm pretty sure you can do:

```
mv * ../..
```

To move something up two directories

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
mv * ../../
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to move two directories up

> mv * ./../../

Comment: the "./" is redunant; it just means "the current directory". The last "/" is not needed either.